# How to combine a dataframe normal column with set column in pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set, string-concatenation

have got a dataframe df

```
item        Space   rem_spc     nxt_item
Pineapple   0.5     0.5         {Mango, Grape}
```

need to combine `df['item']` and `df['nxt_item']` into single column `df['com_item']` as given below

```
item        Space   rem_spc     nxt_item        com_item
Pineapple   0.5     0.5         {Mango, Grape}  Pineapple,Mango,Grape
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`pandas.Series.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) :

```
df["com_item"] = df["item"] + "," + df["nxt_item"].astype(str).str.strip("{}")
```

Output :

```
print(df)

        item  Space  rem_spc        nxt_item                 com_item
0  Pineapple    0.5      0.5  {Mango, Grape}  Pineapple, Mango, Grape
```

Comment: But this brings result with apostrophe like Pineapple,'Mango','Grape'. Apostrophe should not be in the output. how to achieve that ?

Comment: including `.replace({"[']":""},regex=True)` solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html) for set columns and add `item` values:

```
df['com_item'] = df['item'] + ',' + df['nxt_item'].str.join(',')
print (df)
        item  Space  rem_spc        nxt_item               com_item
0  Pineapple    0.5      0.5  {Grape, Mango}  Pineapple,Grape,Mango
```

Or use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df['com_item'] = df['item'].str.cat( df['nxt_item'].str.join(','), sep=',')
```

If need create first sets for deduplicated values in `com_item` is possible add value `item` to set with join in list comprehension:

```
df['com_item'] = [','.join(b.union({a})) for a, b in zip(df['item'],df['nxt_item'])]
```

Sample data for see difference of solutions:

```
print (df)
        item  Space  rem_spc           nxt_item
0  Pineapple    0.5      0.5  {'Mango','Grape'}
1      Mango    0.5      0.5  {'Mango','Grape'}

df['nxt_item'] = df['nxt_item'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['com_item1'] = [','.join(b.union({a})) for a, b in zip(df['item'],df['nxt_item'])]
df['com_item2'] = df['item'] + ',' + df['nxt_item'].str.join(',')

print (df)
        item  Space  rem_spc        nxt_item              com_item1  \
0  Pineapple    0.5      0.5  {Grape, Mango}  Grape,Mango,Pineapple   
1      Mango    0.5      0.5  {Grape, Mango}            Grape,Mango   

               com_item2  
0  Pineapple,Grape,Mango  
1      Mango,Grape,Mango
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want nxt_item as a list:

```
df['com_item'] = df.apply(lambda row: list(row['nxt_item']) + [row['item']] ,axis=1)
```

output:

```
        item  Space  rem_spc        nxt_item                   com_item
0  pineapple    0.5      0.5  {Grape, Mango}  [Grape, Mango, pineapple]
```

if you want as a string:

```
df['com_item'] = df.apply(lambda row: ' '.join(list(row['nxt_item']) + [row['item']] ),axis=1)
```

output:

```
        item  Space  rem_spc        nxt_item               com_item
0  pineapple    0.5      0.5  {Grape, Mango}  Grape Mango pineapple
```